# Erro ao filtrar valores de formulário comparando dois arrays

Tags: php, array, formulário, filtro

Estou tentando filtrar os valores dos campos preenchidos com um array, ou seja, verificar se uma string de um array está contida em algum dos valores vindo de um formulário.

Problemas:

- Apenas o primeiro campo está sendo filtrado com sucesso, o segundo e
  o terceiro não estão sendo reconhecidos.
- O segundo campo não aceita palavras acentuados. Gostaria de corrigi-lo também.
- Percebi que ao chamar um valor referente do array campos preenchidos, não retorna nada. Exemplo: `$dados[2]`, deveria retorna o valor do terceiro campo, já que os valores dos campos são passados como array. Me corrijam se eu estiver errado.

Abaixo está o script para análise:

```
<?php

// trechos à serem COMPARADOS PARA O FILTRO
$filter_ads = array();
$filter_ads[0] = "alid=";
$filter_ads[1] = "slid=";
$filter_ads[2] = "hlid=";
$filter_ads[3] = "plid=";
$filter_ads[4] = "ulid=";
$filter_ads[5] = "llid=";
$filter_ads[10] = "aaa";  
$filter_ads[11] = "123";

// Campos preenchidos para teste
$_POST['link1'] = 'http://www.google.com.br?galid=1';
$_POST['descricao1'] = 'aaaa 1111 1';
$_POST['codigo1'] = '123aa1';

/* VERIFICO SE H? UM POST */
if(count($_POST) > 0) {
    $erro = array();
    $dados = array();  

    /* PERCORRO TODOS OS CAMPOS */
    foreach($_POST as $nome => $valor) {
        /* VERIFICO SE NENHUM CAMPO EST?? VAZIO */
        if (isset($valor) || !empty($valor) || !isset($valor) == '') {
            // procura por campo URL e verifica se foi digitado corretamente
            if ($nome == 'link1' && !preg_match("/\b(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/|www\.)[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]/i", $valor)) {
                $erro[$nome] = 'A <strong>URL</strong> inserida é inválida.'; 
            }
            // procura por campo descricao e verifica se foi digitado no formato "nome de 4 a 100 caracteres alfanuméricos, acentuados e espaços"
            elseif ($nome == 'descricao1' && !preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z\d_ ]{4,100}$/i', $valor)) {
                $erro[$nome] = '<strong>Descrição</strong> incorreta.'; 
            }
            // procura por campo codigo e verifica se foi digitado apenas com 6 algarismos
            elseif ($nome == 'codigo1' && strlen($valor) != 6) {
                $erro[$nome] = '<strong>Código</strong> incorreta.'; 
            }                   
        } else {
            echo "Todos os campos devem ser preenchidos!";  
        }

        // Prepara os valores para serem inseridos no BD removendo todas as tags HTML e espaços em branco inseridas no começo e fim do valor
        $dados[$nome] = trim(strip_tags($valor));                   

    }

    // verifico se h? algum erro
    if(count($erro) == 0) {

        echo "<span style='color:orange;weight:bold;'>VALORES DOS CAMPOS PREENCHIDOS PRA ANALISES:</span><br/>";    
        foreach ($dados as $X) {
            echo "<span style='color:green;'>".$X."</span><br/>";
        }

        echo "<br/><span style='color:orange;weight:bold;'>FILTRADOS COM SUCESSO:</span><br/>";

        foreach ($dados as $X) {
            foreach ($filter_ads as $filter) {
                if (strpos($X, $filter)){
                    echo "<span style='color:red;'>".$X."</span><br/>";
                }
            }
        }

        echo $dados[2]; // OBS: gostaria de saber também porque não mostra o valor referido do array

    }
}


?>
```

Comment: `$dados[2];` é vazio pq seu array `$dados` não tem o índice `2`, só tem índices não numéricos.

Comment: Verdade  @fernandoandrade, eu não pensei nisso. Obrigado. E os outros problemas vc sabe onde está o erro? Preciso muito disso.